# Calling static jave method from .sh file

Tags: java, linux, bash, jar, sh

I have a jar files that holds a lot of classes, in each class there are static methods that I have to call from a shell script.

I have a function class for each module, this class aggregates all the methods in the module.

Example:

```
public class Functions{
    public static String e1(){return e1.e1();}
    public static Integer e2(){return e2.e2();}
}
```

```
public class e1{
    public static String e1(){
        //do something
    }
}
```

```
public class e2{
    public static Integer e2(){
        //do something
    }
}
```

I want to call the functions in the Function class from sh file:

```
result=$jar.Functions.e1()
```

I read that this is the only solution:

> The only java method you can call from a shell script is the main method
> of a class, by starting that class with a java command line execution.

Is this correct?

Comment: I think that you can use `jshell` to do this. Check out its documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/introduction-jshell.htm#JSHEL-GUID-630F27C8-1195-4989-9F6B-2C51D46F52C8

Comment: thank you, i've looked and read about it but i chose another solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I created a module of runners and in this module I created a lot of main classes. Each main class runs a static function as mentioned above.
Then I called the desirable main from the bash function with the `java` command.